# c# linq query extract repeating data types

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of raw data, where always 8 data values are available for one timestamp Date_Time. I would like to use linq to sort the values of Data_Value column by the Data_Type into one row for each Date_Time.

[Rawdata table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUWl3.png)

I have the following class and would like to return it as a list of that class.

```
public class MeasurementData
{
public MeasurementData();

public int Test_ID { get; set; }
public int Channel { get; set; }
public string Date_Time { get; set; }
public double Current { get; set; }
public double Voltage { get; set; }
public double Charge_Capacity { get; set; }
public double Discharge_Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a reduced form of the code, where i just try to extract four values.

```
public static List<DataStructure.MeasurementData>     RawResult(List<DataStructure.MeasurementRawTableSQL> rawData, int _Test_ID)
{
if (rawData != null)
{
    var result = rawData.GroupBy(x => x.Date_Time)
         .Select(gr =>
         {
             var _Date_Time = TicksToDate(gr.FirstOrDefault().Date_Time);
             var _Channel = gr.FirstOrDefault().Channel;
             var _Voltage = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 21).FirstOrDefault().Data_Value;
             var _Current = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 22).FirstOrDefault().Data_Value;
             var _Charge_Capacity = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 23).FirstOrDefault().Data_Value;
             var _Discharge_Capacity = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 24).FirstOrDefault().Data_Value;

             return new DataStructure.MeasurementData
             {
                 Test_ID = _Test_ID,
                 Channel = _Channel,
                 Date_Time = _Date_Time,
                 Current = _Current,
                 Voltage = _Voltage,
                 Charge_Capacity = _Charge_Capacity,
                 Discharge_Capacity = _Discharge_Capacity
             };
         }
         ).ToList();

    return result;
}
else return null;
}
```

This is partially working, for the case 21 and 22 it gives me proper values, whereas I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for the case 23 and 24. On the other hand the database has this rows for every single datapoint and is never null. If I only select First() instead of FirstOrDefault() I get an "sequence contains no elements".

I am really stuck right now and would really appriciate your help.

Comment: Did you check what gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 23) is returning? Is it returning some data? Also I guess you need not write gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 21).FirstOrDefault().Data_Value; rather you can just write gr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Data_Type == 21).Data_Value;

Comment: Change double to double? so where you have null values the code will work.

Comment: You are getting the error due to the time of the data not being exactly the same.  Tow data values could be 100ns different but you want to put into same results.  I would recommend using a round method to group the times.  The round amount would depend on how often you are getting new samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. G_S: Yes, but the query for 23 is not returning any data. @jdweng: Can you explain what you mean by round method or give me a link for an example?

Comment: The Math.Ceiling(), Math.Floor(), and Math.Round() methods.

Comment: @jdweng: You mean the Date_Time Value I use to sum up? The numerical value in that column is for all 8 values always the same. If I try to query one exact value e.g. in sql I get all 8 rows back. Maybe I am wrong here, but if i convert that Date_Time value, which is just ticks, then I get the exact same time as well.

Comment: I can't explain the nulls if the ticks are the same.  Maybe the Data_Type aren't integers (string or float)? Making the type decimal? will allow the nulls, but not solve the issue.

Comment: @jdweng: I tried to convert the ticks to a date string, giving the same result as the ticks for sorting. I changed the type to decimal for all relevant variables and the "raw" data in a datagrid looks quite right, as I dont need so many digits. I thought maybe it has to do with the values in the row as the values for 23 - 25 are something like 0.0001246. I tried to handle them as string, but this gave me the exact same "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the cleanest way of solving issue.  I cannot explain why you are not getting a Data_Type for each time value, but code below should get around the exceptions.  I used decimal? as the type.  The exception is caused when the WHERE returns null you cannot get the property Data_Value.  So you have to test for null like code below :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        //public DataStructures DataStructure = new DataStructures();

        public static List<DataStructure.MeasurementData> RawResult(List<DataStructure.MeasurementRawTableSQL> rawData, int _Test_ID)
        {
            if (rawData != null)
            {
                double? _Voltage = null;
                double? _Current = null;
                double? _Charge_Capacity = null;
                double? _Discharge_Capacity = null;

                var result = rawData.GroupBy(x => x.Date_Time)
                     .Select(gr =>
                     {
                         var _Date_Time = gr.Key;
                         var _Channel = gr.FirstOrDefault().Channel;
                         var _Voltage_Row = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 21).FirstOrDefault();
                         if(_Voltage_Row != null) _Voltage = _Voltage_Row.Data_Value;
                         var _Current_Row = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 22).FirstOrDefault();
                         if(_Current_Row != null) _Current = _Current_Row.Data_Value;
                         var _Charge_Capacity_Row = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 23).FirstOrDefault();
                         if (_Charge_Capacity_Row != null) _Charge_Capacity = _Charge_Capacity_Row.Data_Value; 
                         var _Discharge_Capacity_Row = gr.Where(x => x.Data_Type == 24).FirstOrDefault();
                         if (_Discharge_Capacity_Row != null) _Discharge_Capacity = _Discharge_Capacity_Row.Data_Value; 

                         return new DataStructure.MeasurementData
                         {
                             Test_ID = _Test_ID,
                             Channel = _Channel,
                             Date_Time = _Date_Time,
                             Current = _Current,
                             Voltage = _Voltage,
                             Charge_Capacity = _Charge_Capacity,
                             Discharge_Capacity = _Discharge_Capacity
                         };
                     }
                     ).ToList();

                return result;
            }
            else return null;
        }
    }
    public class DataStructure
    {

        public class MeasurementData
        {
            public int? Test_ID { get; set; }
            public int? Channel { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date_Time { get; set; }
            public double? Current { get; set; }
            public double? Voltage { get; set; }
            public double? Charge_Capacity { get; set; }
            public double? Discharge_Capacity { get; set; }
        }

        public class MeasurementRawTableSQL
        {
            public DateTime Date_Time { get; set; }
            public int Channel { get; set; }
            public int Data_Type { get; set; }
            public double Data_Value { get; set; }

        }
    }
```